# How to save a graphic file in R Studio to an external file with a unique name

Tags: r, graph, rstudio

How can I get Rstudio to save each plot in a separate file on disk when  requesting multiple plots in an R script? this is easily done in R using savePlot command.  It would be nice to use something that worked in both packages.

```
install.packages("RXKCD")
require(RXKCD)
getXKCD(which = "552")
savePlot("fun.emf","emf")
win.metafile("fun.wmf") 
png("fun.png")
```

LOG:

```
> savePlot("fun.emf","emf") #this works in R but not in RStudio
Error in savePlot("fun.emf", "emf") : 
  can only copy from 'windows' devices
> win.metafile("fun.wmf")  #File of size 0 is created
> png("fun.png")           #File of size 0 is created
```

Thank you.
Mary A. Marion

Comment: Check out the graphical devices, e.g. `?png`. Example: `svg('plot1.svg') ; plot(1) ; dev.off()` For ggplot in particular, see `ggsave`.

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do (in Rstudio and in Sublime):

```
png("omg.png", 600, 600)
#pdf("omg.pdf", 7, 7)
plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
dev.off()
```

For pdfs, I'd comment out the png function and I comment the pdf one.